# Запуск кода из программы PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

Делаю собственную IDE с использованием PyQt для графического интерфейса, небольшую, просто для практики.
У меня есть 2 окна: первое окно, где пользователь вводит код, а второе окно - окно вывода, которое будет выводить результат. Как можно реализовать данный функционал?

Comment: В порядке бреда можно, например, документацию почитать

Comment: @Alexander Chernin читал вот здесь https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/. Возможно, не нашел

Comment: Делал когда-то давно: https://github.com/gil9red/dev_window, есть в README скриншот (там PySide+PyQt4, поэтому для PyQt5 придется добавить импорты)

Comment: @gil9red Благодарю

Comment: Простой текстовый редактор [English] https://www.learnpyqt.com/examples/no2pads-simple-notepad-clone/

Comment: Другой редактор [Русский] https://pikabu.ru/story/tekstovyiy_redaktor_na_pyqt_7758171

Comment: @CameUp, тогда, поставьте звезду проекту ;) :D

Comment: @Alexander Chernin Благодарю за статью, но весь вышеперечисленный функционал уже реализован, вот, возник вопрос на этой почве, но и на этот вопрос я уже нашел пару ответов, постараюсь позже выложить ответ

Comment: Тогда надо правильно сформулировать вопрос

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Так я же и написал - нужно запустить программу из программы PyQt, или нужно показать окна и код?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который у вас есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на мой вопрос в этой статье: https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/qprocess-external-programs/

---

upd. Сделал запуск кода через QProcess. Код -> https://github.com/Intercrus/PyQt_IDE

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/590606)

Comment: @Jack_oS Как только допилю код - скину :)

Comment: @CameUp Up ходят слухи он до сих пор пилит))